# Indexable type interface containing values with various types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, interface

Is there any way of achieving type variety in indexable type interfaces?

I have a state which contains fields with different types.

```
public state:State = {
  item: {...},
  item1: {...},
  ...
  itemCollection: [],
  itemCollection1: [] 
  ...
}
```

In the code above `item` is some specific name which I want to access to the state with it like `this.state['item']`. But, as far as I realized, indexable types in typescript only accept values with the exact same type.

I have an interface like:

```
interface State{
  [field:string]: ITEM | ITEM[] | null
}
```

, which I want to be able to turn into something like this:

```
interface State{
  [field:string]: ITEM | null
  [field:string]: ITEM[] | null
}
```

I know it looks stupid. As I am new to TypeScript, I wonder if I could do it like I used to do in JavaScript.

Comment: Look into literal types and intersection types. An interface can't express this but there are types that can

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

> indexable types in typescript only accept values with the exact same
>   type

That's very close, but not exactly correct — the *index signature* must *contain* all types that appear on the right-hand side. It means the type used for indexing can be exactly the same as your values, but can also be wider.

What does it mean for a type to be wider? You can think of types are sets. For example, a specific string like `"foo"` belongs to the set of all strings, so `string` is wider than `"foo"`. The types at the top (`any` and `unknown`) contain almost everything, meaning everything can be assigned to them.

**Solution**

You must use an index signature that contains all possible types of the values.

```
interface State {
  [field: string]: ITEM | ITEM[] | null
}
```

or

```
interface State {
  [field: string]: any;
}
```

However, this will destroy any code completion. If it suits your use case, you could also try this approach:

```
type Foo = {
    foo: number[]
    bar: string[]
    [index: string]: unknown;
}

const foo: Foo = {
    foo: [1, 2, 3],
    bar: ["a", "b", "c"],
    baz: Window
}
```

In this example, we get correct code hints for `foo` and `bar`, and any excess properties are of type `unknown`. This means they need to be verified before they can be used.

```
let unrecognized = foo["baz"]

if (unrecognized instanceof Window) {
    console.log(unrecognized.document);
}
```

Comment: I also considered using `interface State { [field: string]: ITEM | ITEM[] | null }` but my component is quite big and has methods which accept only `ITEM` or `ITEM[]`. This was the real reason of  asking this question. `state` holds both collections and items from each of the collections. That's why the methods accept different types of arguments. 
I went on with the second option `interface State { [field: string]: any }` as I am checking for types while fetching data, as well as, inside the methods. I hope it will not cause any serious type issues.